# Namespace for Credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I wanted to write credential for web services like this

```
private Credentials credentials;
```

But i am getting error to this line that 
    The type or namespace name 'Credentials' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

[Calling Web Service using ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=22760)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's in the `ExtentrixWS` namespace - which means you need the ExtentrixWS library. But are you actually consuming an ExtentrixWS web service?

Comment: i think web-service requires credentials, if i don't use it i get error `The remote name could not be resolved`